# switch statement and incrementation

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 0;
switch (i++)
{
case 1: j += i;
case 2: j += i;
case 3: j += i;
break;
}
printf("%d %d",i, j);
```

The `i++` expression evaluates `i` to 1 since it's a post-increment operator, so the statements in case 1 will be executed, which means `j` is evaluated to 2. Then without breaks, the program continues to execute all the following statements. Since the value of `i` does not change, the value of `j` doesn't either. So I expect the output to be something like `2 2` but it turned out to be `2 6`. Can anyone give me an explanation please, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the value of i does not change, the value of j doesn't either.

Not true.

`j += i` is the same as `j = j + i`, and `i is 2` once **inside** the `switch(..)` statement.

This executed **3 times** gives you `6`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I just thought j+=i is equivalent to j=i+1. So the original value of i (1) will be used to trigger case 1, after that it's set to the incremented value (2) before the statement in case 1 is processed, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The point is that the "switch(i++)" is evaluated before the case statements are processed. Thus i++ will set i to 2. However it will evaluate to 1 since the i++ is a post increment. Thus the first case will be triggered. Since there are no break statements the code will fall through all three resulting in j==6.

Comment: If i evaluates to 1, how can j == 6 at the end?

Answer (score 1):

j will be incremented thrice in the switch block . i will first go to case 1 since i is post incremented .As there are no break statments it will go through all the case statements and thus giving the value 6

Answer (score 1):

A break statement must be added in each case statement to prevent fall through behaviour.
The way you think the code is working goes like:
     1. Switch evaluates i = 1.
     2. Increment i to 2.
     3. Enter switch and execute case 1.
     4. Exit switch.
The way it actually happens:
     1. Switch evaluates i = 1.
     2. Increment i to 2.
     3. Enter switch statement and excute case 1.
     4. Fall through and execute case 2.
     5. Fall through and execute case 3.
     6. Exit switch statement.

For the behaviour you want try:
    switch(i++)
    {
        case 1: j+=i;
            break;
        ... Do the same for case 2 and case 3
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you had done j = i instead of j+= i, the answer which you expected would have come. But you are using j+=i which translates to j = j+i; That means j is getting updated in every step.